# Creating a vertical histogram

Tags: java, histogram

Basically I've been trying to make my histogram display the asterisks vertically aligned above the letter that it is incrementing above. I've been trying to figure out the most efficient way to get the asterisks to align above the letter repeating. Any suggestions?

```
    **My current output displays this horizontally**

asfklafjasjfk
A (3) ***
F (3) ***
J (2) **
K (2) **
L (1) *
S (2) **
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

*I want it to display this*

```
  abcaaaabbzzzzz    
                           *  
  *                        *
  **                       *
  **                       *
  ***                      *
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

I have listed my code below

```
public class histogram {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lettersInput = input.nextLine();
        lettersInput=lettersInput.toUpperCase();
        String map = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int[] count = new int[map.length()];

        for(int x = 0; x <  lettersInput.length();x++){

            int letter = map.indexOf(lettersInput.charAt(x));

            if(letter < 0){

                continue;
            }

            count[letter]++;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < count.length; x++){

            if(count[x]< 1)
                continue;
            System.out.println(String.format("%s (%d) %s",

                    map.charAt(x),

                    count[x],

                    new String(new char[count[x]]).replace('\0','*')));
        }

        System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's exactly wrong with it? What have you tried to solve it? We're not here to debug your code for you.

Comment: I am seeking suggestion on the best way to go about getting the asterisk aligned vertically above the letter it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I took was to use a sorted map, whose keys are letters of the alphabet and whose values are the number of occurrences of each letter.  Simply iterate over the input string to populate the map.  Then, iterate over each row of possible output and print out either a space or an asterisk for each letter.  I used `Collections.max()` on the map's values to find the height of the histogram.

```
TreeMap<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
String input = "abcaaaabbzzzzz".toUpperCase();
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
    Integer val = map.get(input.charAt(i));
    map.put(input.charAt(i), val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
}
Collection<Integer> c = map.values();
int maxFrequency = Collections.max(c);

System.out.println("Input:\n" + input);
for (int i=maxFrequency; i > 0; --i) {
    for (int j=0; j < alphabet.length(); ++j) {
        Integer count = map.get(alphabet.charAt(j));
        System.out.print((count != null && count >= i) ? "*" : " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println(alphabet);
```

**Output:**

```
Input:
ABCAAAABBZZZZZ
*                        *
*                        *
**                       *
**                       *
***                      *
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester